# Centos7 can't connect ot Internet but IP & ssh from local works

Tags: networking, centos

[if this is too long you can read from the bottom]

Hello previously i have this Centos7 and it worked fine with the internet connection with static IP.

The problem started when i installed GUI, first i installed XFCE4 (with gdm) and it worked fine, & the internet works too. Only the gdm login page isn't working properly (blank page with cursor), but that's not the case. As I install Mate (with lightdm) to working login page, it affect the network so that i can't connect to the internet. But i can still SSH to the machine from other computer.

ping status

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.5.39 #local
PING 192.168.5.39 (192.168.5.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.5.39: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.5.39: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.205 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.5.39: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.191 ms
^C
--- 192.168.5.39 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.191/0.198/0.205/0.017 ms
[root@localhost ~]# ping 111.94.248.18 #-- google
connect: Network is unreachable
[root@localhost ~]#
```

here is the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0 file

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0 
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp2s0"
#UUID="bb980114-13c0-4399-a310-9de54c5ddd75"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="FC:AA:14:80:C0:B5"
IPADDR0="192.168.5.20"
PREFIX0="24"
GATEWAY0="192.168.5.1"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
[root@localhost ~]#
```

here is the NetworkManager service status

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status NetworkManager.service
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sel 2015-08-04 05:37:44 EDT; 17h ago
  Process: 865 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 865 (code=exited, status=127)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service

Agu 04 05:37:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit NetworkManager.service entered failed state.
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.
Agu 04 05:37:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit NetworkManager.service entered failed state.
Agu 04 05:38:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Agu 04 05:38:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Agu 04 05:39:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
```

and by running nmcli i got this

```
[root@localhost ~]# nmcli dev status
nmcli: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgudev-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
[root@localhost ~]#
```

which seems to be the problem,, i've came across duckduckgo&google and i guess they got the solution here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1401813 but it only readable by subscribing users (too bad i'm not holding any server business that i can afford the subscribe). anybody got an idea to fix this? Much Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that you've probably moved on from this issue but I'm posting the solution that worked for me in case anyone else comes across it.

I had the same error on Centos 7 and managed to get NetworkManager working again by doing the following:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install libgudev1-devel
```

and then startup NetworkManager as usual:

```
sudo service NetworkManager start
```

Comment: I've run into similar issue, when nmcli (and NetworkManager) would fail to run, resulting in default gateway not being set.